# Why can't I use conservation of energy to find ratio of final velocities on different planets?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, potential-energy

The question is

> An object of mass $m$ is allowed to slide down a frictionless ramp of angle $\theta$, and its speed at the bottom is recorded as v. If this same process was followed on a planet with twice the gravitational acceleration as Earth, what would be its final speed?

My idea is to use conservation of energy to solve this.
So,

$K_i + U_i = K_f + U_f$

I'm going to plug in what I think I can (and this might be where I'm going wrong):

$0 + mgh = \frac{mv^2}2+0$

Solving for  v:

$\sqrt{2gh}=v$

So if $g$ doubles, then v is multiplied by a factor of $\sqrt 2$. However, the answer is that v doubles as well.

Note that the question here is not what the correct solution is, because I have that. My question is where I went wrong.

EDIT: Since you all say that I'm not doing anything wrong, I guess the question becomes what is the book doing wrong?

Here is the solution that the book gives.

The normal fore will cancel out the perpendicular component of gravity, leaving $mg \sin \theta$ as the net force on the object.

$F_{net} = mg \sin \theta  = ma$

$a = g \sin \theta$

This shows that $a$ is proportional to $g$. Then, using $v = v_0 + at$ we can see that the final speed is proportional to a. So if this planet has double the value of $g$, the object will experience double the acceleration, leading to double the final speed.

Comment: As far as I can see your analysis is correct. It even follows by dimensional analysis, without doing any math.

Comment: @Javier I agree that OP is right, but how can one tell it by using just _dimensional analysis_?

Comment: @TheGhostOfPerdition: The only possible relation between $v$, $g$ and $h$ is $v \propto \sqrt{gh}$.

Comment: @Javier yes, but the OP is confused btw the factors $2$ and $\sqrt 2$, how would these factors change the dimension?

Comment: @TheGhostOfPerdition I edited it to give the solution that the book provides

Comment: @Javier I edited it...^

Comment: The issue is that you are keeping the height constant while the book is keeping the time duration of sliding constant.

Comment: I would get a refund on that book

Comment: @PeterR It's the Princeton Review AP Physic C book.

Comment: Please see [our guide](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6413/how-do-we-write-good-question-titles) on writing good titles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The velocity does not double if the acceleration is doubled. The relevant SUVAT equation is:

$$ v^2 = u^2 + 2as $$

where in this case $u=0$ so we get:

$$ v = \sqrt{2as} $$

A doubling of acceleration means that the velocity would double if the travel **time** was kept constant. However in this case it's the travel **distance** that is held constant. The greater acceleration means the object covers the constant distance in less time, so the doubled acceleration acts for a shorter time. That's why we get the square root dependence of velocity on acceleration.

Comment: they may have meant by "the same process" the same duration of sliding.

Comment: then it would be double the speed

Comment: The question talks about *a frictionless ramp of angle* $\theta$. It doesn't say anything about the length of the ramp being changed.

Comment: I've edited the updated question